# What is the best way to add to the dimensions of a 3d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a NumPy array that is sized: (54,41,2) How would I most efficiently resize it to (57,41,2) such that the additional three in the 57 dimension have zero for their values?

I did this but I'm not sure it is correct:

```
final_data = np.zeros((57, 41, 2))
final_data[:smaller_data.shape[0]] = smaller_data
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.concatenate` is a good candidate. It's explicit and this is what it was designed to do.

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(3**3).reshape(3,3,3)
>>> b = np.zeros((2,3,3))
>>> np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)
array([[[  0.,   1.,   2.],
        [  3.,   4.,   5.],
        [  6.,   7.,   8.]],

       [[  9.,  10.,  11.],
        [ 12.,  13.,  14.],
        [ 15.,  16.,  17.]],

       [[ 18.,  19.,  20.],
        [ 21.,  22.,  23.],
        [ 24.,  25.,  26.]],

       [[  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.]],

       [[  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.]]])
```

You have to keep in mind that in numpy, arrays are usually stored in a contiguous fashion. That's why appending to an array (in any axis), will result in a *new* array, because the array required a new memory location.

Remark: it does the same as `np.vstack` in this case, although I find using `vstack` more logical when limited to 2D arrays.

Comparing `np.concatenate` to your original approach in which you first define an array of zeros and then overwrite a part of the array, it depends on the size of the arrays involved. In any case the speed gain is small:

```
In [14]: a = np.random.random((100,100,150))

In [15]: %timeit original_way(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.77 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit concat_way(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.93 ms per loop

In [17]: 2.93/3.77
Out[17]: 0.7771883289124669

In [18]: a = np.random.random((1000,100,150))

In [19]: %timeit original_way(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 64.6 ms per loop

In [20]: %timeit concat_way(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 64.8 ms per loop
```

If this is the bottleneck in an application of yours, you'll be looking for non-numpy solutions.

Comment: concatenate probably does it in the original way, just written in C code.

Comment: @hpaulj, I was thinking about that as well, although it would not fill with zeros, just a `malloc` (`np.empty`) or such. In any case, taking the Zen of Python into account, this time I'd go for the explicit way: more readable.